.NET Localization - Windows Forms and Resource Files
I've started using Localization with resource files in my application. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 17.11 (the one with the new Resource Explorer)
I'm facing some problems and here's a brief list:

Every time I add a new language (by selecting it from the drop down list of the Form), all new resources are added to the Resources Explorer, even Location, Size, Name and other properties like TabIndex and stuff. The thing is, I want to translate only the Text or Label , not the entire location and position of the control. Every time I change something in design view, I have to remember to change its position/size/.. in every language and this is soooo frustrating.

I see a lot of empty red fields in the new Resource Explorer. Sometimes when I save the solution, a bunch of error starts to pop-up, so I have to restart visual studio, delete .vs hidden folder inside solution folder and recreate the resource files.


I think I would like to switch to a more practical Globalization solution other than Resource Files. I have to maintain 3 or 4 languages in my applications, and it's so frustrating.
Any ideas?
Thank you!

If you don't want to change positioning/sizing for the different languages according to the size needed for text in that language are you ok that controls might overlap because of that or text is cut of when it doesn't fit?

Yes I'm OK with that. I want to change the position only if I have to. So maybe  I would add the position/sizing entry in resx file. Is this possible to do?

Don't know. I never really used the built-in localization. And i don't have an alternative ready. I had to do localization in multiple projects and never used the same methods twice as the other factors like "Who does the translation" or "when translation will be done" are typically the driving factors on how todo it and they are always different. I always ended up writing my project specific own toolchain.

The problem with built-in localization is that there isn't a practical way to switch between languages. To change text I have to switch the language for all forms to see how they look. I'm a plc/hmi designer and in those IDEs you have a central location for text, and you can switch the editing language as you wish. Also alerts and message boxes are globalized as well. With VS, instead I have to dynamically load the text on runtime and change the code accordingly. Least of all, I don't have so much time to the deadline unfortunately.

There are two very effective and easy ways to work with globalization in WinForms. The first that I will recommend is the i18n.NET library, which allows you to avoid direct interaction with RESX files, a significant advantage.
This is more suitable for smaller or newly started projects
In the case of legacy projects (the majority of WinForms projects), the most viable alternative is the tool ResXManager. This tool assists with all the controls, making the updating and maintenance of translations much easier.

Does that work for text set in the winforms designer? He uses the designer to design his form so all of his strings to be localized will be in resx files or in the designer.cs. Not in code files where a call to Localize can be simply added.

No, it doesn't work to set text in the WinForms designer. However, everything you configure via the designer is auto-generated code in the .Designer.cs file. He mentioned he wants to switch to a more practical globalization solution rather than using resource files. He will need to modify his .Designer.cs file to retrieve the texts from i18n.NET instead of using resource files.

With forms with hundreds of elements this becomes impractical. To build an HMI for example you have to see where each label or button goes with the appropriate text inside. I can't fiddle with Designer.cs each time I add/remove something.

Ahh, I see. Have you already looked into ResXManager? It might be helpful.

Wow! You're my savior! I didn't know about this tool. I will definitely use it! Thank you! It's way more practical even than MAT (multilingual app toolkit) and I can clearly see only texts and labels. That's exactly what I wanted. There's also an option to create a resource directly from the code (e.g. the message inside a messagebox)  thank you very much!

I will complement the answer, which might be helpful for others.
